# Chrome devtools: computed style different from calculated CSS rules?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug some table display. In the "Computed" section of DevTools, it says that `display` is set to `table-cell`, even though the top ranked rule is set to `display: block !important`.

Screenshot:

[image]

I've never seen this before, and I now have no idea how to debug my styles.

What could be causing the computed styles to be different from the top-ranked rules?

Comment: Can you provide anything more than a picture? Some code? Or even better, a jsFiddle / CodePen?

Comment: My question's really about why Chrome Devtools is showing incorrect information, rather than about why my specific code isn't working.

Comment: If we can see the code you're using it should help us determine why you're seeing the results you are in the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks. It took a while to extract the code into a reproducible form but here it is (I've made it a separate question about the CSS problem, and will keep this one specifically about the odd behaviour in Devtools): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369454/responsive-tables-code-works-on-jsfiddle-but-not-in-browser

Comment: OK, so it seemed the problem was that I didn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my HTML, just in case that helps anyone in future!