# Identical CSS working on JSFiddle, broken in browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table

I'm trying to make responsive tables using the [No More Tables](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#no-more-tables) approach.

I've simply copied and pasted the code from the example above. It works fine on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcp62x7t/

But identical code in my browser does not work fine. The tables do not behave nicely when I reduce the size of the browser window:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Here's the complete HTML file that I'm trying in my browser: I've tried it in both Safari and Chrome on OSX and get the odd behaviour above.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  #no-more-tables table,
  #no-more-tables thead,
  #no-more-tables tbody,
  #no-more-tables th,
  #no-more-tables td,
  #no-more-tables tr {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  #no-more-tables thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

  #no-more-tables td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align:left;
  }

  #no-more-tables td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
  */
  #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

<section id="no-more-tables">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th class="numeric">Price</th>
      <th class="numeric">Change</th>
      <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
      <th class="numeric">Open</th>
      <th class="numeric">High</th>
      <th class="numeric">Low</th>
      <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
      <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
      <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
      <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
      <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
      <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
      <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
      <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
      <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: The problem in the browser seems to be that the `<td>` elements are still set to `display: table-cell` even though I've explicitly styled them with `display: block`:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an image?

Comment: Thanks, but an image of what? I've included a screenshot of the broken styles, and a screenshot of the curious behaviour in Devtools. It should be possible to reproduce the problem using the HTML I've provided.

Comment: Tried `display: block !important;`?

Comment: @Hareesh yup, doesn't help. Really curious to know what the bug is....

Comment: ...and Devtools already seems to think that `display: block` has the highest weighting, so it's very odd that it is still using `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the media query tag `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {}`, it works fine after.

**UPDATE: Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixed the problem.**

Comment: Makes no difference in my browser, I'm afraid.

Comment: Tested in my computer, Copied the same code from jsfiddle and works fine :( (windows)

Comment: Yes, the JSFiddle version is fine. But does the HTML file that I pasted into the question work for you?

Comment: The point is that the HTML pasted into the question should be identical to the JSFiddle version, but it's actually not working. So there must be some subtle difference between the two.

Comment: No, same problem but after removing media query it works well. Try to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of your html and check.

Comment: Oh wow, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is what makes the difference. THANK YOU! Why would this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I thinks those `data-title="Code"` are html5 attributes.